# open jsp with disabled mode

Tags: jsp, struts2, ognl

I have a form which the user fills with its details & the same form is visible to the admin in the disable mode. Also there are few fields the admin can edit according to its role. So basically in the admin mode there are two buttons to UPDATE & VIEW. 
I tried implementing it using a session variable opMode. And added a scriptlet in jsp according to the opMode the fields are visible. But here I had to COPY the same fields thrice.
Example :

```
     <% String opMode=(String)session.getAttribute("opMode");%>

       <%if(opMode.equals("ADD")){ %>          
        <s:textfield name="caserecord.case_Name" label="Case Name." size="25" />
        <%}%>  

       <%if((opMode.equals("VIEW")){ %>          
       <s:textfield name="caserecord.case_Name" label="Case Name." size="25" disabled="true"/>
        <%}%> 

        <%if((opMode.equals("UPDATE")){ %>          
       <s:textfield name="caserecord.case_Name" label="Case Name." size="25" />
        <%}%>
```

So is there a way in which I can use the same jsp for all the three tasks ie. **ADD, VIEW & UPDATE** without having to duplicate the fields.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I had to COPY the same fields thrice. I didn't understand this point. please explain what code is duplicated.

Comment: I used a scriplet & for all 3 values in the session I made 3 form tags with same fields in it.

Comment: please share the code that is duplicate to make a clear picture.

Comment: see i have update my question. For the same case name I had to add three text boxes for different modes.

Comment: what is difference between first and third case.

Comment: it is just for example purpose. According to different user roles the update fields(unable/disable) will change. Anyways the question is, is there a way to use one single textbox and keep it disabled for view mode & unable for update mode

Comment: @Pradnya Set a variable based on whatever business logic you have and use that variable as the disabled attribute value.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the field using OGNL like

```
<s:if test="#session.opMode in {'ADD', 'VIEW', 'UPDATE'}">
  <s:textfield name="caserecord.case_Name" label="Case Name." size="25" disabled="%{#session.opMode == 'VIEW'?true:false}"/>
</s:if>
```